# Run the javascript before render the page by react JSX function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following resources:

test.js

```
var gblData;

function getData(){
    //webservice to set value to gblData
}
```

React jsx file

```
//use the gblData to render the html page
```

html file

I tried the following ways to call the getData() before the jsx file so that gblData is not undefined. But it is failed.

1 html body onload function

2 jquery document ready

Comment: try putting your ```test.js``` script in the ```<head>``` tags of your html page, or you can use the ```defer``` attribute on both the script tags to make them execute in order [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup)

Answer (score 1):

Is your `React.renderComponent` call after everything else? Try the following.
You can have your jsx file declare all your components, but you can render them from another file.

```
var glbData;
function getData(){
  ...
  ...
  React.renderComponent(<YourComponent/>, document.body);
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6d5mw4y2/1/).