# Script tag running before DOM is loaded

Tags: javascript, html

I believe the script tag is running before the DOM elements are loaded. How would I go about waiting for the elements to be loaded first? I've tried wrapping the script tag's content in `window.onload = () => {}` but no luck. I've also tried `<body onload="myFunc()">`.

My logic is to hide the React content in `root` if the browser is Edge/IE and show the `unsupportedBrowser` content to let the user know that this browser is not supported.

Note this only happens in IE.

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="root">React Content</div>
    <div id="unsupportedBrowser" style="display: none;">
       Microsoft Edge is NOT supported.
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" defer>
       document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
        if (window.document.documentMode || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1) {
             alert("Edge browser");
             document.getElementById("root").style.display = "none";  //ERROR here, rest doesn't run
             document.getElementById("unsupportedBrowser").style.display = "block";
             // do other things
        };
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding `defer` to your script tag

Comment: If the `<script>` tag is after the HTML that creates the element, it should find it.

Comment: Check for typos in the ID. The code you posted should work.

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Comment: If it says "none is undefined", the problem is that you forgot the quotes around `"none"`.

Comment: Funny I found this and came back here to see this. Thanks Barmar!

Comment: May [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26478468/run-the-javascript-before-render-the-page-by-react-jsx-function) help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe React is giving you a hard time, since it gets still executed when you include the source for it.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
             if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1) {
                 alert("Edge browser");
             
                 document.body.innerHTML = '<div id="unsupportedBrowser" style="display: none;">Microsoft Edge is NOT supported.</div>'
            }else{
                var root = document.createElement("div");
                root.setAttribute("id", "root");
                document.body.appendChild(root);
                
                var react_script = document.createElement("script");
                react_script.setAttribute("src", "your_script");
                document.body.appendChild(react_script);
            }
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

A side note: I don't get why you exclude the Edge browser. Edge != Internet Explorer. These days all major browser support the standard browser APIs. For browser compatibility you should also use Babel to transpile it down.

Comment: I'm actually targeting both Edge and IE. Edge has some support for React but some plugins aren't showing up, such as Semantic UI cards. The solution you provided works well in Edge, but not in IE. Nothing seems to happen in IE.

Comment: @SimonWong Internet Explorer has a different user agent. http://useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php?name=Internet+Explorer

Comment: I edited my original post. I'm using `window.document.documentMode` to target IE browsers

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1) {
```

with:

```
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edg") > -1) {
```

Last version of Edge returns:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
  Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36 Edg/85.0.564.41"
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't really answer my question regarding to why the script is not working